# Can't display full height of background image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to have a image as a background in a div and I want it to be responsive and scale like a image inside  tag when browser is resized. But I'm doing something wrong here, because I the image isn't full height!? It's onlye 80px in height. The image is 1500 x 650 px. If I set the height to 650px, then it's working, but then it has the same height despite a smaller browser window! Preciate some help to solve this problem.

```
<div id="introContainer">   
<h1>Test</h1>
</div>


#introContainer
{
background-image: url('bilderGuide/bilderLayout/bgStart2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: What browsers are you testing it in?  Mobile Safari has a lot of problems with `background-size: cover`. Is that where you're encountering the problems?

Comment: @RyanMitchell No, I'm using Firefox. Is there any other way to do this that is working also in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Use 100% height. See this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/huloxewo/1/edit?html,css,output

Tested on Chrome and Safari on a desktop.

The CSS:

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}

#introContainer
{
    background-image: url('someImage.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 650px;
}
```

**EDIT**: Updated my answer to address the comment

Comment: This covers all of the screen! I just want it to start with a height of 650px and then get smaller in height while I resize the window.

Comment: @3D-kreativ Try out the updated JSBin link. I've updated my answer. You just need to add a `max-height` property.

Comment: But the height is the same all the time! I want it to get smaller when I resize the window. Isn't that possible?

Comment: @3D-kreativ It's becoming smaller for me when I resize the window but I haven't tried it on Firefox. What OS are you using?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Just tried it on Firefox and it works fine there as well. The image shrinks when I reduce the window size and it doesn't grow past 650px when I enlarge the window

Comment: I'm tesing in Chrome with Windows7. When I test your link in fullscreen I have the same height of the element al the time, but the image is scaling some. But I want the background image to act just like a commin image inside the <img> tag. The hole picture is visible all the time and it's getting smaller only in height. I hope you understand me?

Answer (score 0):

It's 80px in height because the content of your "div id="introContainer" is only that big (div adjusts by content). Maybe try to give your div a fixed position with bottom: 0px and top: 0px; It will adjust according to the window height. This works for me:

```
.coverDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-image: url('../../Images/Backgrounds/HongKong.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jquery, very simple.

**Advantage** : don't need to know the size of the image

Live exemple : http://jsbin.com/tukodame/1/edit?css,js,output

**CSS**

```
#introContainer
{
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = $('#introContainer').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
var bgImgHeight = img.height;  
$('#introContainer').height(bgImgHeight);
```